# Get a field from Fragment on Adapter and get List from Adapter on Fragment

Tags: android, checkbox, fragment, adapter

I'm making a list of `checkbox` with itens on my `adapter` and my `fragment` has one checkBox on the top of the list with "Select All" and on the bottom of the list a `textView` "x Itens Selected" plus a `button`.

My problem 1 is how to get this "x": the count of how many checkboxes are checked, because they are on `Adapter` and the `TextView` is on `Fragment`, I can't set it on `Adapter`.
To get this, I'm using a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` from the list of checkboxes.
I've tried to get Fragment from Adapter with a lot of ways but without success. Sending on constructor, getting from viewHolder, getting from `getSupportFragmentManager()`, `getFragments()`, `getFragmentById`, `getFragmentByTag`.
I've tried `FragmentObserver` also, but it didnt work.

Problem 2: So I've tried to make a list on `Adapter` with all the checked Itens, but I need to send it to `Fragment` to manage it. Also, I can't get it from `Adapter` on `Fragment` (on `onCreateView`).

Can someone help please?

My `Adapter.java` `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PedidoItemRefugadoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    //pedidoItem is each object from the list
    final PedidoItem pedidoItem = itensRefugados.get(position);

    //checkCadaItemRefugado is each checkbox from Adapter
    holder.checkCadaItemRefugado.setText(pedidoItem.getItemPedidoObservacao(context));

    holder.checkCadaItemRefugado.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int count = 0;
            int size = itensRefugados.size();
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
                if (holder.checkCadaItemRefugado.isSelected()) {
                        count++;
                        //itensRefugadosChecked is the new list with all the checked items
                        itensRefugadosChecked.add(pedidoItem);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My XML `Adapter`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/frame_layout_notificacao"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check_cada_item_refugado"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Item: Pedido: \nMotivo:"/>

            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My XML `Fragment`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="br.com.zapgrafica.appzap.fragments.ItensRefugadosFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_itens_refugados"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Selecionar todos"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/itens_refugados_layout_swipe_to_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_itens_refugados_total"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_itens_refugados_total"
            android:text=""/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_itens_refugados_total"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/itens_refugados_confirmar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeButtonAjusteOnlineRefugo"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using interface.
Create your interface class, initialize it in adapter class and implement it in your fragment. So when you will need to send any value to fragment, use method which you have created in interface to send data to fragment. You will get checked checkbox values in fragment. [Refer this link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating). Hope this will help you.

Comment: It helped a lot! Thank you so much!

Could you please help me with my holder.checkCadaItemRefugado.setOnCheckedChangeListener ?
The event is working fine. But I would like to run all the list and check how many itens of the list are checked. And which of them (to add on my new list). 
The code inside my loop for isn't working.

Comment: You can use SparseBooleanArray to maintain your checkbox items if checked or  unchecked. You just need to save position of array value and set true if checked else remove that position from SparseBooleanArray(check before removing it if that position is available or not).

Comment: I wish you could be more specific in your solution, @Artipatel. In my adapter, I initialized it with the following: public interface DataChangeListener {
        void onDataSetChanged();
    } and implemented in my FragmentA (where the checkbox is displayed) the following: public class GroupFragment extends Fragment implements GroupListAdapter.DataChangeListener and Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        // Data has changed, do something about it, like telling the adapter and doing anything you see fit.
    }. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: As you said that you initialised that interface in you adapter class.
Have you called  onDataSetChanged method on changelistener of check box?